# Visual Studio 2013 - Delete file from solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I opened a solution in Visual Studio with some files/folders. Inside of windows explorer, I deleted 2 files inside of a folder within the solution. The files are locked in visual studio, and they can't be found because I deleted them.

How can I delete those files from Visual Studio? They are locked in solution explorer and they can't be found because they were deleted in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Maybe inspect your .csproj file of the project from Windows Explorer? Then manually remove any references from there.  Not ideal, but may help?

Comment: That fixed it! If you make that an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely inspect your .csproj file of the project from Windows Explorer. Then manually remove any references from there. Not perfect, but should help.

Comment: please provide more details..
how to do it.

Comment: Open the csproj file in a text editor, use Ctrl+F to find the reference to your file, then modify accordingly.  This is deliberately vague: there may be a renamed file and you need to change it, or you may need to remove it completely; it depends on what you are trying to achieve.